# Get all future date using cron expression between 2 dates

Tags: java, spring, cron

I want to get all future date using cron expression between 2 dates(start and end dates).
By using below code I can get the next date only. I want a list of future dates.

```
 CronSequenceGenerator cron = new CronSequenceGenerator("cron-expression");
    cron.next(new Date())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CronSequenceGenerator.next()` [gives you the next date in the cron job sequence *after* the date passed in](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html#next-java.util.Date-). So if you want a list of dates, just keep passing in the date it spits out until you reach the date you wish to stop at.

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
Date start = new Date();
while (start.before(end)) {
    start = cron.next(start);
    dates.add(start);
}
```

Comment: @boycod3 `start` and `end` are your boundary dates. (`start` is then "reused" in the loop of course, but you could easily break that out into a separate variable should you so wish.)